# Flutter Dart update dynamic data using variable on a map to get data using provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I want assign _slug on a variable map. The error shoes The instance member '_slug' can't be accessed in an initializer. When I set static keyword it works. But I want to set the value dynamically.
Here is my code .

`

```
class SingleProductFetchProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late String _slug;
  void onClicked(BuildContext context, {required String slug}) {
    _slug = slug;
    notifyListeners();
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      MyRoutes.productDetails,
    );
  }

  Map<String, String> singleProductVariable = {"slug": _slug};

  Future<ProductDetailsModel> singleProductFetch() async {
    // print(_productSlug);
    QueryResult queryResult = await qlclient.query(
      QueryOptions(
          document: gql(QueryDocument.productDetailsSingle),
          variables: singleProductVariable),
    );

    var data = queryResult.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
    var body = ProductDetailsModel.fromJson(data);
    return body;
  }
}

// Future<void> _fetchUsers() async {
//   _homeState = HomeState.Loading;
//   try {
//     await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
//     final apiusers = await UserApi.instance.getAllUser();
//     users = apiusers;
//     _homeState = HomeState.Loaded;
//   } catch (e) {
//     message = '$e';
//     _homeState = HomeState.Error;
//   }
//   notifyListeners();
// }

  // Future<List<ProductDetailsModel>> productDetailsFetch(String slug) async {
  //   late List<ProductDetailsModel> productd = [];
  //   print(slug);

  //   if (condition) {
  //         return productd;
  //   }

  // }
  // String get my => _productSlug;

  // var _text = "samsung-galaxy-a53-5g-8gb-128gb-free-gift-updated-9";

  // var varibalbe = {"slug": ""};
```

`

I want to get set the slug variable dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to assign a map to a string from the concept you can't assign a map to a string however, you can convert the map to a String and then assign it or also you may go with **jsonEncode()** it will work let me know if you need a proper explanation.

Comment: Please give me a proper explanation how can I do that